# CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class

Tags: css

Not sure is this possible? Trying to make that card-horizontal class not follow the same style as the parent col. Please see below:

```css
.-horizontal_image, .-horizontal_content {
    color: red;
}

.parent [class*="col-"]:not([class*="card-horizontal_"]):first-child {
    color: orange;
}

.parent [class*="col-"]:not([class*="card-horizontal_"]):last-child {
     color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="col-4">
6789 should be orange
<a>
<div class="col-4 -horizontal_image">image red</div>
<div class="col-6 -horizontal_content">12345 red</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
more 12345 should be yellow
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you asking, but I think this gets you there. Use ^ versus * ... * is any match, where ^ starting match

```css
.-horizontal_image, .-horizontal_content {
    color: red;
}

.parent [class^="col-"]::first-child {
    color: orange;
}

.parent [class^="col-"]::last-child {
     color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="col-4">
6789
<a>
<div class="col-4 -horizontal_image">image</div>
<div class="col-6 -horizontal_content">12345</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
more 12345
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: um, in this way, whatever on the col- won't turn to orange and yellow

Answer (score 0):

I think the following combinations might get you the colours you want, if I understood your question correctly.

**See demo below**

```css
.parent > .col-4:first-child {
  color: orange;
}

.parent .-horizontal_image,
.parent .-horizontal_content{
  color: red;
}

.parent > .col-4 + .col-4 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col-4">
    6789 should be orange
    <a>
      <div class="col-4 -horizontal_image">image red</div>
      <div class="col-6 -horizontal_content">12345 red</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    more 12345 should be yellow
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is will solve my question. Thank you, everyone.

```css
.-horizontal_image, .-horizontal_content {
    color: red;
}

.parent [class^="col-"]:not([class*="horizontal_"]):first-child {
    color: orange;
}

.parent [class^="col-"]:not([class*="horizontal_"]):last-child {
     color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="col-4">
6789
<a>
<div class="col-4 -horizontal_image">image</div>
<div class="col-6 -horizontal_content">12345</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
more 12345
</div>
</div>
```